# Handling morerows in table

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am working on html to xml data conversion, my problem is when a entry contain morerows than all following rows that affected with that should auto increase there column number.

**Input xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Name</td>
        <td colspan="2">Marks</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>56</td>
        <td>45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**input xslt**

```
   <xsl:template match="table">
    <table>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="tr">
    <row>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </row>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="td">
    <xsl:variable name="tdnum" select="count(preceding-sibling::td[not(@colspan)])+sum(preceding-sibling::td/@colspan)+1"/>
    <entry name="col{$tdnum}">
        <xsl:if test="@colspan">
            <xsl:attribute name="namest" select="concat('col', $tdnum)"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="nameend" select="concat('col', ($tdnum + @colspan - 1))"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="@rowspan">
            <xsl:attribute name="morerows" select="@rowspan"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </entry>
</xsl:template>
```

**current output**

```
<table>
    <row>
        <entry name="col1" morerows="2">Name</entry>
        <entry name="col2" namest="col2" nameend="col3">Marks</entry>
    </row>
    <row>
        <entry name="col1">56</entry>
        <entry name="col2">45</entry>
    </row>
    <row>
        <entry name="col1">...</entry>
        <entry name="col2">...</entry>
        <entry name="col3">...</entry>
    </row>
</table>
```

**expected output**

```
<table>
<row>
    <entry name="col1" morerows="2">Name</entry>
    <entry name="col2" namest="col2" nameend="col3">Marks</entry>
</row>
<row>
    <entry name="col2">56</entry>
    <entry name="col3">45</entry>
</row>
<row>
    <entry name="col1">...</entry>
    <entry name="col2">...</entry>
    <entry name="col3">...</entry>
</row>
```

only want to rearrange numbering of column, for sample i created rowspan in first entry but there are many instances where it appear in 2nd or 3rd entry than colname s/b arrange at per appearnce of input.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change variable to

```
<xsl:variable name="tdnum" select="count(preceding-sibling::td[not(@colspan)])+sum(preceding-sibling::td/@colspan)+1"/>
```

to

```
<xsl:variable name="tdnum">
        <xsl:call-template name="current-cell-position"></xsl:call-template>
```

and define template for this

```
    <xsl:template name="current-cell-position">
    <xsl:message select="count(preceding::td)"></xsl:message>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="generate-id(parent::tr) = generate-id(ancestor::table[1]/descendant::tr[1])">
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(preceding-sibling::*[matches(local-name(.), '^(td|th)$')]/(if (@colspan) then number(@colspan) else 1)) + 1"/>                
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="sum(parent::tr/*[matches(local-name(.), '^(td|th)$')]/(if (@colspan) then number(@colspan) else 1)) = sum(ancestor::table[1]/descendant::tr[1]/*[matches(local-name(.), '^(td|th)$')]/(if (@colspan) then number(@colspan) else 1))">
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(preceding-sibling::*[matches(local-name(.), '^(td|th)$')]/(if (@colspan) then number(@colspan) else 1)) + 1"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="ancestor::table[1]//*[@rowspan][1]">
            <xsl:apply-templates
                select="(parent::tr/preceding-sibling::tr[sum(*[matches(local-name(.), '^(td|th)$')]/(if (@colspan) then number(@colspan) else 1))
                = sum(ancestor::table/descendant::tr[1]/*[matches(local-name(.), '^(td|th)$')]/(if (@colspan) then number(@colspan) else 1))][1]/*[1])[1]"
                mode="find-matrix-column">
                <xsl:with-param name="stop-id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)"/>
                </xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="row-count" select="
                    if (parent::tr/preceding-sibling::tr[sum(*[matches(local-name(.), '^(td|th)$')]/(if (@colspan) then number(@colspan) else 1))
                    = sum(ancestor::table/descendant::tr[1]/*[matches(local-name(.), '^(td|th)$')]/(if (@colspan) then number(@colspan) else 1))][1])
                    then (count(parent::tr/preceding-sibling::tr[sum(*[matches(local-name(.), '^(td|th)$')]/(if (@colspan) then number(@colspan) else 1))
                    = sum(ancestor::table/descendant::tr[1]/*[matches(local-name(.), '^(td|th)$')]/(if (@colspan) then number(@colspan) else 1))][1]/preceding-sibling::tr) + 1)  else 1"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="not(preceding-sibling::*[matches(local-name(.), '^(td|th)$')]|preceding-sibling::th)">1</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(preceding-sibling::*[matches(local-name(.), '^(td|th)$')]/(if (@colspan) then number(@colspan) else 1))"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="find-matrix-column">
    <xsl:param name="stop-id"/>
    <xsl:param name="matrix"/>
    <xsl:param name="row-count"/>
    <xsl:param name="col-count">1</xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="current-position" select="concat('[R', $row-count, ':C', $col-count, ']')"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($matrix,$current-position)">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="find-matrix-column">
                <xsl:with-param name="stop-id" select="$stop-id"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="matrix" select="$matrix"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="row-count" select="$row-count"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="col-count" select="$col-count + 1"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="generate-id(.)=$stop-id">
            <xsl:value-of select="$col-count"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:variable name="next-col-count" select="if (not(following-sibling::*)) then '1' else if (@colspan) then $col-count + number(@colspan) - 1 else $col-count + 1"/>
            <xsl:variable name="new-matrix-values">
                <xsl:if test="@rowspan">
                    <xsl:call-template name="add-to-matrix">
                        <xsl:with-param name="start-row" select="number($row-count)"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="end-row" select="number($row-count) + number(@rowspan) - 1"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="start-col" select="number($col-count)"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="end-col" select="if (@colspan) then number($col-count) + number(@colspan) - 1 else number($col-count)"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="following-sibling::*">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]" mode="find-matrix-column">
                        <xsl:with-param name="stop-id" select="$stop-id"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="matrix">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$matrix"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$new-matrix-values"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="row-count" select="$row-count"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="col-count" select="$next-col-count"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="../following-sibling::tr[1]/*[1]" mode="find-matrix-column">
                        <xsl:with-param name="stop-id" select="$stop-id"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="matrix">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$matrix"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$new-matrix-values"/>
                        </xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="row-count" select="$row-count + 1"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="col-count" select="1"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="add-to-matrix">
    <xsl:param name="start-row"/>
    <xsl:param name="end-row"/>
    <xsl:param name="current-row" select="$start-row"/>
    <xsl:param name="start-col"/>
    <xsl:param name="end-col"/>
    <xsl:param name="current-col" select="$start-col"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$current-col > $end-col"/>
        <xsl:when test="$current-row > $end-row">
            <xsl:call-template name="add-to-matrix">
                <xsl:with-param name="start-row" select="$start-row"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="end-row" select="$end-row"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="current-row" select="$start-row"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="start-col" select="$start-col"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="end-col" select="$end-col"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="current-col" select="$current-col + 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>[R</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$current-row"/>:C<xsl:value-of select="$current-col"/><xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="add-to-matrix">
                <xsl:with-param name="start-row" select="$start-row"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="end-row" select="$end-row"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="current-row" select="$current-row + 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="start-col" select="$start-col"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="end-col" select="$end-col"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="current-col" select="$current-col"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

if any have better idea than suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in defining your requirements rather than in writing XSLT code to implement those requirements.

If I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve (and I'm not sure I do), I would have thought you can achieve it by adding to the column number ($tdnum) the difference between the maximum number of columns for all rows in the table, and the number of columns in the current row.

To code that, you might find it useful to calculate the max number of columns within the match="table" template, and pass it as a tunnel parameter to lower-level templates. I would do the calculation using a function:

```
max(tr/f:col-count(.))
```

with

```
<xsl:function name="f:col-count" as="xs:integer">
  <xsl:param name="row" as="element(tr)"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="sum($row/td/(if (@colspan) then number(@colspan) else 1))"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKay for your help, but main issue is that when we identify the difference in column, how can we analyse the colname, in this example it is first column that is achieve but what when second column of previous row is spanned etc..

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can help any further without more clarity of requirements.

Comment: We have Issue that when any td has attribute morerows than colname of that td should not appear in following tr. just like in expected output you see that first entry has colname="col2" because in preceding row first td has attribute morerows, therefore all following tr there is no col1 entry @morerows-1 times.

Answer (score 1):

I believe @Rupesh_Kr has a small error.

```
 <xsl:variable name="next-col-count" select="if (not(following-sibling::*)) then '1' else if (@colspan) then $col-count + number(@colspan) - 1 else $col-count + 1"/>
```

should be

```
 <xsl:variable name="next-col-count" select="if (not(following-sibling::*)) then '1' else if (@colspan) then $col-count + number(@colspan) else $col-count + 1"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Jack Briner, Thanks for Highlighting that issue